# OpenCV: Applying Operations on RGB Images (Split+Merge)

Tags: c++, opencv

Sorry if this question is so basic, I'm new with OpenCV.

I want to apply histogram equalisation to an RGB image. HE only works for single channel so I figured that I have to split the image into 3 different channels, apply HE to each one of them, then merge them all together to form output equalised image.

So I did just that and here's my program which I REALLY believe should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("/Users/Documents/red.jpg");  //Load image file
cvNamedWindow("Trans-in", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );     //Create input window
cvNamedWindow("Trans-out", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE  );   //Create output window

cvShowImage("Trans-in", img );  //Show input image in input window

//Create space for outputs rgb and its separate channels, r, g and b
IplImage* img0 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);    //rgb
IplImage* r = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);    //r
IplImage* g = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);    //g
IplImage* b = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);    //b

//cvZero(r);
//cvZero(g);
//cvZero(b);

cvSplit(img, b, g, r, NULL);       //OpenCV likes it in BGR format

cvEqualizeHist( img, r );    //equalise r
cvEqualizeHist( img, g );    //equalise g
cvEqualizeHist( img, b );    //equalise b


cvMerge(b, g, r, NULL, img0);  //merge all separate channels together to output image rgb

//cvReleaseImage(&r);
//cvReleaseImage(&g);
//cvReleaseImage(&b);

cvShowImage("Trans-out", img0); //Show output image in output window


cvWaitKey(0);
cvReleaseImage( &img);
cvReleaseImage( &img0);

cvDestroyWindow( "Trans-in");
cvDestroyWindow( "Trans-out");

return 0;
}
```

Apologies if the //comments are a bit annoying, but it shows my 'reasoning' I guess. Xcode didn't complain until I hit the 'Run' button. It basically crashed (input image shows, but not output image).

Plus an error message at the bottom:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (CV_ARE_SIZES_EQ(src, dst) && CV_ARE_TYPES_EQ(src, dst) && CV_MAT_TYPE(src->type) == CV_8UC1) in cvEqualizeHist, file /opt/local/var/macports/build/_Volumes_work_mports_dports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp, line 2414 terminate called throwing an exception
```

And I have no idea what it means or what to do next.

Comment: You are using the C++ tag but the C API of OpenCV. If you are new to OpenCV you should not learn the C API, instead use the C++ API! See http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html#code

Comment: Oh dear, I will check this again. I noticed that c++ opencv tends to use 'Mat' instead of 'IplImage' but insofar my other (but simple) programs seems to have worked well (my programming language is c++)

Comment: Hi again, I've typed the program exactly as in the link in your post but Xcode is complaining "Conversion from string literal to 'char*' is deprecated". There are 2 of this message in the 2 lines beginning with char*.

Comment: Well, this is a whole different topic. But you could always do this: std::string str = "string";
const char *cstr = str.c_str();

Comment: Just curious to know...do you get a correct image after equalizing each R,G,B plane and then combining them? Your process is not the correct way to equalize colored images.

Comment: donno how you accepted the split method as the answer...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization

Comment: @rotating_image... I know that equalization by channel splitting is incorrect and the correct way is to perform Intensity equalization of HSV/HSI/YUV etc. I just answered the actual question that why was the program causing assertion failture. OP didn't ask if this method is theoretically correct or not.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm completely new with OpenCV so I just follow the examples in the official OpenCV textbook (haven't moved on to using mat types though). In the 'histogram equalisation' section of the book, it says that for RGB images you need to separate the channels first and then apply HE to each one. So that's what I did. The code given by sgar91 works, at least, I get a higher contrast output image. I can't confirm absolutely though because I haven't (well, don't know how to) seen the actual histogram. @rotating_image...I can't confirm if your method works because I didn't test it, but thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `cvEqualizeHist` function incorrectly in the following lines:

```
cvEqualizeHist( img, r );    //equalise r
cvEqualizeHist( img, g );    //equalise g
cvEqualizeHist( img, b );    //equalise b
```

`img` is a 3 channel image while `r`,`g` and `b` are single channel images. `cvEqualizeHist` doesn't work on 3 channel images.

You have to do the following:

```
cvEqualizeHist( r, r );    //equalise r
cvEqualizeHist( g, g );    //equalise g
cvEqualizeHist( b, b );    //equalise b
```

Comment: WAIT, it still doesn't work! The program is still crashing but there's no error message this time

Comment: At line "cvShowImage("Trans-out", img0);" there is a small message saying "Thread : Breakpoint 1.1"

Comment: oh my goodness, I don't know what happened, I have just run the program again (I did NOT edit anything else) and it works! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @sgar What if we want to give the images values of our own choice or we put condition on their values like `cv::split(img, bgr); if bgr[0] > 127.0;`

Comment: @Ahmad... To apply condition, use [`cv::threshold`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold) with `cv::THRESH_TRUNC` option. Or if you just want to set all pixels to same value, use [`setTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=setto#mat-setto) like this: `bgr[0].setTo(value);`.

Answer (score 2):

For doing histogram equalization to a RGB image...convert it to HSV image and then equalize the V plane...

1. convert RGB to HSV
2. split HSV into H,S and V
3. equalize V
4. merge H,S and V

   ```
   vector<Mat> hsv_planes;
   cvtColor(image,image,CV_BGR2HSV);
   split(image,hsv_planes);
   equalizeHist(hsv_planes[2],hsv_planes[2]);
   merge(hsv_planes,image);
   cvtColor(image,image,CV_HSV2BGR);
   ```